# `CallerArgumentExpression` is always null (C# 10)

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, c#-10.0

I'm trying to use the [`CallerArgumentExpression` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callerargumentexpressionattribute?view=net-5.0), in conjunction with the suggestion for validating records [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70182148/706346), but the expression is always null. I am doing this in a .NET6 Core console application. The exact same code works fine in LinqPad 7 (.NET6).

I have a base `record` that contains common validation methods (pretty much copied from that other answer)...

```cs
  public record CommonValidation {
    internal static bool NonEmptyOrNullString(string s, [CallerArgumentExpression("s")] string expr = default) {
      if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)) {
        throw new ArgumentException($"{expr} cannot be null or empty");
      }
      return true;
    }

    internal static bool NonZeroInt(int n, [CallerArgumentExpression("n")] string expr = default) {
      if (n < 0) {
        throw new ArgumentException($"{expr} cannot be negative");
      }
      return true;
    }
  }
```

I can then create a `record` as follows...

```cs
  public record Address(string Street, string City, string State, string Country, string Postcode) : CommonValidation {
    private bool _ = NonEmptyOrNullString(Street)
                     && NonEmptyOrNullString(City)
                     && NonEmptyOrNullString(State)
                     && NonEmptyOrNullString(Country)
                     && NonEmptyOrNullString(Postcode);
  }
```

If I try to create an `Address` with an empty `State`...

```cs
Address a = new("5 My Street", "Somewhere", "", "Oz", "12345");
```

...then the exception is thrown, but the `expr` variable is null. As I said, the exact same code works fine in LinqPad, even though both are using the same version of .NET/C#.

Anyone able to explain what's going wrong in the console app? Thanks

Comment: Just thrown your code into a VS2022 Net 6 Console app and have no problem with it. Works as expected.

Comment: @Ralf Yup, I had created the project in VS2019, so even though I changed it to .NET6, it was still targetting C#9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visual Studio 2019 doesn't support C# 10. Make sure you're using Visual Studio 2022. LinqPad 7 does which is why it works there.

Comment: Duh, ain't oi the stoopid one! I had created it in VS2019 and changed the target to net6.0, forgetting that this still left me with C#9. Thanks